# How to calculate the average of the 2 previous rows when a zero is found in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have thousand of rows in excel and I need to average the 2 preceding rows every time a zero is found. For example

```
Column1

23
12
0
32
10
0
```

I need the average of 23 and 12 to replace the zero found in the third row. As well as the average of 32 and 10 to replace the zero found in the sixth row. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without using VBA this requires an extra/helper column.

[image: Worksheet Screenshot]

Enter the following formula in `B2` and ctrl-enter/copy-paste/fill-down the rest of the column:

```dart
=IF(A2<>0,A2,(INDEX(A:A,ROW()-1)+INDEX(A:A,ROW()-2))/2)
```

See [this post](//superuser.com/a/1331666) for tips on how to easily fill the formula down a large number of rows.

If you need the the original column modified, simply copy the second column and Paste Special as Values into the the first one.

Comment: This works great, thank you! However, if by chance, is it possible to average the preceding and the succeeding non zero if a zero is found? Like in the example I wrote above, it would be like (12+32)/2 for the third column. Apologies if it's inappropriate to ask sub-questions in the comment section.

Comment: @Karl Technically sub-questions are frowned upon, but very simple ones like yours are OK. Just use `ROW()+1` instead of `ROW()-2`. `ROW()` returns the current row index, so `ROW()-1` is the previous row, and `ROW()+1` is the next row.